# System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<ModelName> does not contain a definition for

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, begincollectionitem

I am trying to use [Steve Sanderson's blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) about editing a variable length list. I've installed the dll via the NuGet package manager and made sure that the namespace is in the `Views/web.config` file. However, I the following error when I attempt to write the `using` statment.

```
System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Monet.Models.AgentTransmission> does not contain a definition 
for 'BeginCollectionItem' and no extension method 'BeginCollectionItem' accepting a first 
argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Monet.Models.AgentTransmission>' could be 
found (are you missing a using directive or an assmebly reference
```

**Views/Web.config**

```
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <add namespace="HtmlHelpers.BeginCollectionItem" />
    </namespaces>
```

**Partial View (updated)**

```
@model Monet.Models.AgentRelationshipCodes

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("AgentRelationshipCodes"))
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EffectiveDate, "NullableDate", new { @class = "relCodeDate2" })</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RelationshipId, "NullableDate", new { @class = "relDistCode1", maxlength = 3 })</td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RelCodeOrdinal)
    </tr>
}
```

**Controller (just in case)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Transactions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Xml;
using Monet.MonetToDss;
using Monet.Common;
using Monet.Models;
using Monet.ViewModel;
using HtmlHelpers.BeginCollectionItem;

public ViewResult NewRelationshipCode()
{
    return View("AddRelationshipCodePartial", new AgentRelationshipCodes());
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please try to close and re-open the solution for the changes to be picked up by editor. After doing that I don't get the error

> System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper does not
>   contain a definition  for 'BeginCollectionItem' and no extension
>   method 'BeginCollectionItem' accepting a first  argument of type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be 
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assmebly reference

Comment: This is a good point, particularly if after the change, the exception still references AgentTransmission instead of AgentRelationshipCodes.

Comment: This, combined with the answer above, seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

It is a third party library by Steve Sanderson, which you have to install first from https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/:

```
Install-Package BeginCollectionItem
```

Answer (score 3):

I needed to add

```
<add namespace="HtmlHelpers.BeginCollectionItem" />
```

to the namespaces in the web.config of the Views folder.  Mine was in an "Areas" folder so I needed to add it in the Views folder there.

You can also add a using statement right on the view instead, but then you have to remember to add it to each view.

Answer (score 2):

For .Net Core

Install nuget package:- https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItemCore

and then add this on **_ViewImports.cshtml**: `@using HtmlHelpers.BeginCollectionItemCore;`

Answer (score 1):

This is a stab in the dark, but have you tried removing the index specifier [i]? You shouldn't need one when using the BeginCollectionItem helper, as far as I recall. It generates the unique index itself.

Here are a couple more resources on the helper that I found useful:

http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/
http://justmycode.blogspot.com/2012/07/learning-mvc-editing-variable-length.html

Update: Example in reference to asker's comment

```
    @model Monet.Models.AgentRelationshipCodes

    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("AgentRelationshipCodes")) @*error displays here*@
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.EffectiveDate, "NullableDate", new { @class = "relCodeDate2" })</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.RelationshipId, "NullableDate", new { @class = "relDistCode1", maxlength = 3 })</td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.RelCodeOrdinal)
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: How would I reference a property of the collection item without specifying the index? I tried `Model.AgentRelationshipCodes.RelationshipId` but that is highlighted as an error.

Comment: Looking at your code further, you actually want to reference the AgentRelationshipCodes model, not the AgentTransmission model. Then you would use Model.RelationshipId directly.

Comment: Yeah, just saw that :) I am still getting an error on `Html.BeginCollectionItem("AgentRelationshipCodes")` however.

Comment: In fact if I step through the part of the code where the partial is rendered it crashed on the `@using(Html.BeginCollectionItem()` line

Comment: Yes, I hear you, but any issues with the way it's configured will likely be throwing an exception on that line.

Comment: Unfortunately still getting the same error. Does it matter which controller the `PartialViewResult`/`ViewResult` method is coming from?

Comment: No it shouldn't. I also noticed that most of the examples did not explicitly return a PartialViewResult either - so I removed that comment. Can you provide an update of the current exception message? Is it referencing the AgentRelationshipCodes model now?

Comment: Man... so I changed the model to `AgentRelationshipCodes` and the partial view is no longer having a problem with `Html.BeginCollectionItem`. However... it is still throwing an error on this `using` statement. Now when the program gets to this line the debugger simply blows up and I get an `AccessViolationException was unhandled` message saying `Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`