# Html.BeginForm() not passing the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, html.beginform

I have the following cshtml form:

```
model Scraper.Facade.PlayerRow

@using (Html.BeginForm("Calculate", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive table-hover">
    @foreach (var player in Model.AttribsPlayerLine)
    {
        <thead>
            <tr class="success">
                @foreach (var attrib in player.AttribsPlayerList)
                {
                    //@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => Model.tytul)
                    <th data-field="@attrib.attribName">@Html.DisplayFor(x => attrib.attribName) </th>
                }
            </tr>
            <tr class="active">
                @foreach (var attrib in player.AttribsPlayerList)
                {
                    <td data-field="@attrib.attribValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => attrib.attribValue)</td>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>

    }
</table>

<input class="btn-danger"  type="submit" name="Next >>" value="Next >>" />
}
```

which is displaying correctly and then I am trying to get the model in the following controller ActionResult

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Calculate(PlayerRow model)
{
    GenericHelper _genericHelper = new GenericHelper();
    return View();
}
```

However the PlayerRow model is always null.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my model definition

```
public PlayerRow LoadHtmlDoc(string fileLocation)
{
        List<Attrib> attribsHeaderList = new List<Attrib>();
        var playerRow = new PlayerRow();
        playerRow.AttribsPlayerLine = new List<AttribLine>();

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument { OptionFixNestedTags = true };

        // There are various options, set as needed

        // filePath is a path to a file containing the html
        htmlDoc.Load(fileLocation);
}

public class PlayerRow
{
    public List<AttribLine> AttribsPlayerLine; 

}
```

---

UPDATE

Hi All, I changed a bit the logic of my application, basically having 2 lists which has the Header Attributes, and the Attributes for all the players, so only 2 classes now, and I changed the cshtml like this, which is working now :-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Calculate", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =        "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive table-hover">
    <tr>
        @for (int k = 0; k < Model.HeaderAttributes.Count; k++)
        {
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.HeaderAttributes[k].AttributeName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.HeaderAttributes[k].AttributeName)
            </td>
        }
    </tr>


    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PlayerList.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PlayerList[i].PlayerName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PlayerList[i].PlayerName)
            </td>
            @for (int j = 0; j < Model.PlayerList[i].AttributesList.Count; j++)
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PlayerList[i].AttributesList[j].AttributeValue)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PlayerList[i].AttributesList[j].AttributeValue)
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
    }

</table>


<input class="btn-danger" type="submit" name="Next >>" value="Next >>" />
}
```

Now my problem is, who to award the Answer, since I can say that most of the Answers were really helpful to arrive to my solution

Comment: Try a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` and use `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AttribsPlayerLine[i].attribValue)`. If this doesn't work, learn how `EditorFor` is used and try `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.AttribsPlayerLine[i])` which will surely work.

Comment: Hi mostruash, tried what you said but it did not work

Comment: Your `foreach` loop is creating multiple inputs with duplicate `id` (invalid html) and `name` attributes (cant be bound to a collection). You need `for` loops or custom `EditorTemplates` for typeof `AttribLine` as @mostruash as stated.

Comment: @Johann, You should not have accepted an incorrect answer (others viewing this may waste endless time believing that it works - it does not!). Create you own answer and accept it (and remove your last edit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working example of what you're trying to do.  This is about as a close as I can get you.

Let's start with the simplified models:

```
public class PlayerRow
{
    public List<AttribLine> AttribsPlayerLine { get; set; }
}

public class AttribLine
{
    public string attribName { get; set; }
    public string attribValue { get; set; }
}
```

Note that it is IMPORTANT to include the { get; set; } on each model property  so the model binder knows it's on the block for binding.

Next is a simplified view looking only at the form() section:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Calculate", "PlayerRow", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
        @*/*Build out header*/*@
        <tr>
            @foreach (AttribLine a in Model.AttribsPlayerLine)
            {
                <th>@Html.Label("title", a.attribName)</th>
            }
        </tr>
        @*/* Add row of our player attributes */*@
        <tr>
            @foreach (AttribLine a in Model.AttribsPlayerLine)
            {
                using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("AttribsPlayerLine"))
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBox("attribValue", a.attribValue)
                        @Html.Hidden("attribName", a.attribName)
                        @*
                           /* Add any more [AttribLine] properties as hidden here */
                        *@
                    </td>
                }
            }
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input class="btn-danger" type="submit" name="Next >>" value="Next >>" />
}
```

Note that it is IMPORTANT here to make sure that even though a property is not editable by the user, it needs to be included as a hidden element inside our CollectionItem so the model binder can SET it on the [POST]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi pnm, it is giving me an error, "Cannot resolve BeginCollectionItem

Comment: ok added the Nuget, and did not give any problems.  However the model is still null!

Comment: looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436360/system-web-mvc-htmlhelpermodelname-does-not-contain-a-definition-for sounds like restarting visual studio should fix your issue (?)

Comment: can you add the model def to your question please?

Comment: restarted VS but nothing new.  Added my model def

Comment: for AttribsPlayerLine, are the only two properties {attribName,attribValue}? if so try dropping that first tr tag and loop to see if that's confusing the model binder

Comment: AttribPlayerLine is a class and has the following         public List<Attrib> AttribsPlayerList = new List<Attrib>();

Comment: and Attrib has the following  :-   public string attribId { get; set; }
        public string attribName { get; set; }
        public string attribValue { get; set; }
        public int attribValuePosMult { get; set; }

Comment: Should I replace the Edit with the top one?  Even in your edit this x => attrib.attribName is not valid since I have attrib.AttribPlayerList, so I need an indexer to get the attribName

Comment: Thanks pnm, actually I did not see your solution before coming to my Answer, but I have awarded it to you since you helped me a lot to arrive to my conclusion.  Thanks!

Comment: Your note "Note that it is IMPORTANT to include the { get; set; } on each model property so the model binder knows it's on the block for binding." helped me: VS auto-generated a property with `{ get; internal set; }`, so on a hunch based off your comment I dropped the `internal` so it was just `{ get; set; }` and that fixed it: the value from the view was now being bound to the ViewModel property.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly passing the model to the view, but once it gets to the view, the model data will essentially be 'cleared' unless you either edit it or pass it on the next controller, in this situation "Calculate".

I'm not sure exactly what parts of the viewmodel you want passed to the controller, but you can always use this:

```
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DataYouWantPassedToController)
```

Now, you can always use these items also to pass data if you want to edit/change:

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataYouWantToEditAndPass)... and so on.
```

If you simple loop through data without changing or passing it, like you do in the @foreach, the data will be lost during your 'Post' method.

Comment: No luck Eli.  I tried to add the following     @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.AttribsPlayerLine) and when I put a breakpoint there is data, however when I press the submit button, the model is still null.  Also EditorFor did not work, still not getting any data

Comment: Hmmm that is very weird. Should definitely be giving you a partially filled data viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

Try use a `@Html.EditorForModel()` like this:

```
@model Scraper.Facade.PlayerRow

@using (Html.BeginForm("Calculate", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()

    <input class="btn-danger"  type="submit" name="Next >>" value="Next >>" />
}
```

Create a file named `PlayerRow.cshtml` as PartialView on the folder Views/Shared/EditorTemplates and add the following code:

```
    @model Scraper.Facade.PlayerRow
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive table-hover">
        @foreach (var player in Model.AttribsPlayerLine)
        {
            <thead>
                <tr class="success">
                    @foreach (var attrib in player.AttribsPlayerList)
                    {
                        //@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => Model.tytul)
                        <th data-field="@attrib.attribName">@Html.DisplayFor(x => attrib.attribName) </th>
                    }
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    @foreach (var attrib in player.AttribsPlayerList)
                    {
                        <td data-field="@attrib.attribValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => attrib.attribValue)</td>
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>

        }
    </table>
```

I think that this will help you.